# Accessing JMeter HTTP Request Defaults values

Tags: jmeter

I'm using HTTP Request Defaults to set host and port for a set of requests.
I'd like to access the same host value for cookie domain. Is there a way to refer to that particular variable?

Something like this maybe?

```
${DEFAULT_HOST}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. There are no such default variables to access the HTTP Request Default Values.

But - you can easily achieve this using **User Defined Variables**.

Just create a variable `DEFAULT_HOST=www.google.com`

Then update the server name of the HTTP Request Defaults to **${DEFAULT_HOST}**

You can also access the hostname everywhere in your test by using ${DEFAULT_HOST}.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing. Instead of looking for request default variable I used another variable to specify the default.

Answer (score 2):

And for extra credit...

Add a User Defined Variables element to the beginning of the test, so you can pass arguments from the commandline.  In my tests, i have

```
name=HOST
value=${__P(host,test.mysite.com)}
```

Then you can use ${HOST} for HTTP and cookie defaults (and anything else), and run your test from the commandline like

```
jmeter -n -t mysite_loadTest.jmx -Jhost=www.mysite.com
```